# Avoid google login function to call on every page

Tags: php, google-plus

I integrate google and Facebook login to my website. And set a condition either a person can log in with FB or with google. Now the problem is my google login function automatically works if my gmail account is open in the same browser.

```
    function loggedOut(href){
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                gapi.auth2.init();
    });
        setTimeout(function(){
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            //console.log('User signed out.');
            document.location = href;
        });

        }, 2000);
}

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var fullName = profile.getName(),
    imageUrl = profile.getImageUrl(),
    email = profile.getEmail(),
    provider = 'Google';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/google-login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { provider: provider, fullName :fullName, imageUrl : imageUrl, email: email },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data == 1){
                location.reload();
            } else if(data.trim().match("^Entered")){
                alert(data);
                loggedOut('This Page URL');
            }
        }
    });
};

$('#log-out').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    loggedOut(href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

Put this inside a function , called login and call it only on user click on login button. That should prevent google from automatically detecting user . Or you can remove this line totally.